# using jQuery to assign an html value, but after that jQuery returns old value, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am using a jQUery AJAX call to assign the value of a table cell.  The cell is a subtotal, mysubtotalB. That works great as you can clearly see the results.  However at the end of the success function, included is a call to another jQuery function.  The next function is supposed to get the new value just assigned to mysubtotalB and add it to Total A/table cell mysubtotalA.

The part that is odd, is that even after the new value is assigned on screen to mysubtotalB, the value returned via a jQuery statement is 0, or the original value.  Playing with it for a while I noticed that if I ran a second AJAX call and assigned another value to mysubtotalB, the I got the previous value.  That is, the value returned by the jQuery assignment was always one value old. Guessing maybe the DOM did not update on the first call or maybe it has to do with the order of execution, even if the total is assigned before the call is made to the second function.

Does anyone know why this is and what to do about it.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Total A</th>
<td id='mysubtotalA'>0.00</td><!-- default state when page loads -->
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Total B</th>
<td id='mysubtotalB'>0.00<td><!-- default state when page loads -->
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Grand total</th>
<td id='mygrandtotal'>0.00<td><!-- default state when page loads -->
</tr>
</table>

$.ajax({
...
success: function(returned){
$('#mysubtotalB').html(returned);//works fine returned value now on screen in mysubtotalB
}
)};

<script>
...
var theReturnedValue = $('#mysubtotalB').html();
alert('theReturnedValue');// outputs "0" the first default value
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of asynchronous functions.

Comment: alert('theReturnedValue'); outputs string theReturnedValue

Comment: Script 2 fires before Script 1 finishes executing it's asynchronous request. Like @Blazemonger says, welcome...

Comment: `$('#mysubtotalb').html(returned)` - with lowercase 'b'. ` theReturnedValue = $('#mysubtotalB').html()` - with capital 'B'

Comment: this is just a mock up but will change the example.  That is not the real issue though

Comment: Also did a blizzard of alerts to include all variables plus typeof.  Pretty sure the issue is most like it is explained.  Then again...?

Comment: The issue is the async nature of ajax, as noted in the first comment?

Comment: Okay, and that nature is accurately described as? and therefore IE, the DOM does not update when..., so always use parameters or an object... to use a returned value in different functions immediately?

Answer (score 0):

What if you assigned the value of theReturnedValue in the success function call?

```
var theReturnedValue; //declare outside function so you can use it later
$.ajax({
.....
success: function(returned){
$('#mysubtotalb').html(returned);//works fine returned value now on screen in mysubtotalB
theReturnedValue = returned; //assign the value
alert(theReturnedValue); //alert the user
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Tried that.  As a matter of fact pretty much exactly like that on one iteration. Also moved it to the calling page, top of the .js page, in and out of every function, var myvar= ...  myvar= ..., etc.  Looks like a better work around is to pass the values as a parameter or set up an object.  I was more interested in why to better understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get this to work was to set up an object and set an object attribute equal to the returned value.  So created an object in the calling page,

```
var mynewobject = new Object();
mynewobject.sumA = 0;
mynewobject.sumB = 0;
```

Then in the success: function(),  set the value of the appropriate attribute to the returned value:

```
...    
success:  function(returned){
mynewobject.sumB = returned;
....
```

Then in the nested function loop in the .js file, set a variable to that value;

```
....
var someothernewvar = mynewobject.sumB;
....
```

That way as able to set values with an AJAX call and  pass the values inside of multi nested loops reliably.